# "subjecting the components" means what?

Tags: meaning

"Aseptic processing is the process of minimizing entry of viable microbial and particulates into products - typically involves subjecting the components (drug product, container, enclosure) to separate sterilization methods before they are brought together."

what is the meaning of "subjecting the components" in this context?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Have you looked up _subject [sth to sth]_ in a good dictionary? If doing so didn’t answer your question, please edit it to explain why not, as well as what it did tell you.

Comment: I have no idea how a Question about "subjecting" could move on.

Does "Aseptic processing is the process of minimizing entry of viable microbial and particulates into products… " fail grammar, semantics and style?

How are "microbial" and "particulates" comparable?  

Are the components subjected merely to separate sterilization before being brought together"?

"Aseptic processing is the process of minimizing entry of viable microbial and particulates into products - typically involves subjecting the components (blah) to separate sterilization methods before they are brought together."

Answer (score 2):

"Subjecting the components to the process" just means "Carrying out the process on the components". If you do something to an object or a person you **subject** it or them to whatever it is you are doing.

For example a baker might **subject** bread dough to kneading and a police officer might **subject** a suspect to questioning.